# Showing fragment inside popup window

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm working on showing fragment inside popup window. But I'm getting error in showing in that. I googled it for solution. But still not solving this one. Please help me. I'm new to android. My code is

MainActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        View popUp = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup_item, null);
        window = new PopupWindow(getApplicationContext());
        window = new PopupWindow(popUp,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,true);
        window.setAnimationStyle(android.R.style.Animation_Activity);
        window.showAtLocation(popUp, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
        window.setFocusable(true);
        window.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    }
```

popupitem.xml //for showing fragment in MainActivity

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <fragment 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/popup_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.popupemoji.PopupFragment"
        android:tag=""/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have a class extending Fragment with only two line of code on onCreateView

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_item, container);
        return view;
```

Am I wrong anywhere. Logcat error is

```
01-23 14:25:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2868): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-23 14:25:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2868): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.popupemoji/com.example.popupemoji.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
01-23 14:25:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2868):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
01-23 14:25:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2868):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-23 14:25:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2868):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-23 14:25:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2868):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-23 14:25:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2868):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-23 14:25:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2868):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-23 14:25:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2868):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
01-23 14:25:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2868):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 14:25:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2868):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-23 14:25:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2868):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-23 14:25:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2868):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-23 14:25:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2868):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-23 14:25:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2868): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
01-23 14:25:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2868):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
01-23 14:25:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2868):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
01-23 14:25:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2868):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
01-23 14:25:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2868):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-23 14:25:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2868):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
01-23 14:25:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2868):     at com.example.popupemoji.PopupFragment.onCreateView(PopupFragment.java:15)
01-23 14:25:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2868):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
01-23 14:25:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2868):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:900)
01-23 14:25:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2868):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1082)
01-23 14:25:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2868):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1184)
01-23 14:25:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2868):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:291)
01-23 14:25:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2868):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
01-23 14:25:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2868):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
01-23 14:25:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2868):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
01-23 14:25:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2868):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-23 14:25:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2868):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
01-23 14:25:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2868):     at com.example.popupemoji.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
01-23 14:25:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2868):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-23 14:25:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2868):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-23 14:25:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2868):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-23 14:25:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2868):     ... 11 more
01-23 14:25:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2868): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #6: Duplicate id 0x7f080002, tag , or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.example.popupemoji.PopupFragment
01-23 14:25:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2868):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:296)
01-23 14:25:24.005: E/AndroidRuntime(2868):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
```

Comment: you have `View popUp = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup_item, null);` ie inflate `popup_item` then again in fragment you have View view = `inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_item, container);` inflate same layout. also why no use a dialog fragment?

Comment: @Raghunandan: I tried basic dialog fragment. But the main.xml layout need to be rearranged automatically since I'm populating at the bottom. I found it difficult and main layout won't rearrange.

Comment: @Raghunandan: I need to display emoji just like in whatsapp. I have library which includes fragment in it. How do they display sliding emoji in popupwindow.

Answer (score 1):

If I am reading your code correctly, you are creating a View by inflating your popup_item.xml layout. This layout contains a Fragment, which also inflates the popup_item.xml.

Thus that Fragment will also have another Fragment inside of it with the popup_item.xml layout, and this will keep going on indefinitely.

Your error shows that the application is crashing because of this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #6: 
    Duplicate id 0x7f080002, tag , or parent id 0x0 with another fragment 
    for com.example.popupemoji.PopupFragment
```

Because of this popup_item.xml nesting, multiple Views have the same ID, which is a problem. Even if multiple Views could have the same ID, you would have an infinitely nesting Fragment, which would also be a problem.

Comment: So what should I do to make it run properly?

Comment: Though it is hard to say without knowing more about what you are trying to accomplish, I would point at what you inflate in your Fragment as the culprit. Instead of inflating a layout containing your  Fragment in that Fragment, you should probably be inflating a layout containing buttons, text, or other such Views.

Comment: What I'm trying is that I need a emoji just like whatsapp. I have a library for emoji which contain fragment. That's where I'm stuck.

Comment: If you have a library that provides a Fragment, then why are you defining your own Fragment?

Comment: I am getting the same problem with that also. That's why I'm trying with simple fragment.